# Why this Python Program has never generated a YouTube video URL that actually plays a video?

Tags: python, youtube

I wrote a code to play a random YouTube video.

But, every time I generate random URL's and open it in browser, YouTube displays Video Unavailable.

Is there any Algorithm YouTube uses to generate video ID's or I am out of luck every time?

Thanks for reading my question.

```
import random;
import webbrowser;
str='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-_'
list=list(str)

num=int(input("How many URL's : "))

for i in range(num):
        random.shuffle(list)
        char=''
        for i in range(11):
            j=random.randint(0,63)
            char+=str[j]

        url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+char

        print('\n'+url)
        webbrowser.open(url)
```

Comment: How many different URLs could your program generate? About how many videos do you think are stored on YouTube?

Comment: This program generates a random video URL which may or may not match an actual YouTube video URL

Answer (score 0):

> Why this Python Program has never generated a YouTube video URL that actually plays a video?

Youtube has existed since the middle of February, 2005. Since then, about 480 million seconds have elapsed. The population of the Earth is about 7.8 thousand million people.

The video IDs have 64 possibilities for each of 11 symbols, for about 74 million million million in total.

If everyone on Earth had uploaded a new video to Youtube every second continuously since the beginning, without stopping for anything else, that would make about 3.7 million million million videos - i.e., still only about 5% of the available IDs.

> Is there any Algorithm YouTube uses to generate video ID's or I am out of luck every time?

As far as I know, they are chosen more or less randomly. The intent of the system is to make it unlikely that a new video ID has been used before, while allowing multiple servers to process new videos simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Karl.